# Convert Repo to Branch (Keep Commits) in Github

Tags: git, github

I have a Github repo, say it is called `MyRepo`. I created an updated version of that repo called `MyRepo2`. Is there some way to **hide/delete `MyRepo` while keeping the commits active on my profile?** Or perhaps a way to **turn `MyRepo` into a branch on `MyRepo2`** to **keep the commits**?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

> while keeping the commits active on my profile

Not sure, considering the [criteria used for counting commits on your profile page](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#contributions-that-are-counted)

> Commits will appear on your contributions graph if they meet all of the following conditions:
>
> - The email address used for the commits is associated with your GitHub account.
> - The commits were made in a standalone repository, not a fork.
> - The commits were made:
>
>   - In the repository's default branch (usually `master`)
>   - In the `gh-pages` branch (for repositories with project sites)

You might try and fetch your first repo into your second repo, and use the `first_repo/master` branch as your local `gh-pages` branch, to force those commits to be counted.